# Extract parameters and their values from query string in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, parameters

So let's suppose I have a string like

`"param1=value1&param2={"url":"http://somesite.com?someparam=somevalue&someparam1=somevalue1"}&param3=value3"`

and I need it to be:

`param1: value1`

`param2: {"url":"http://somesite.com?someparam=somevalue&someparam1=somevalue1"}`

`param3: value3`

What would be the best approach to parse this in Java? So far I could not found a solution with standard Java libraries, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I've tried with (but it would not work if I put there only query parameters like mine):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/something.html?one=11111&two=22222&three=33333";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
    System.out.println(param.getName() + " : " + param.getValue());
}
```

Comment: url.split("=") - how about this?

Comment: Nope, it would split value from json as well

Comment: could the json part contain the '&' character ? if not, use url.split("&")

Comment: Yeap it could, I forgot to mention this, there could be a link as well with a few parameters

Comment: Is the list of parameters names known to you ?

Comment: Do you by any chance always have the same number of param with same name ?

Comment: Yeap I do know the parameters name and number, so there would be only specific number of them, 3 params if be more specific.

Comment: trick `URLEncodedUtils` by addind what is needed to make it a proper url. `"schema://domain?"` is sufficient. Or create a proper URI that contains only a query : `new URI(null, null, null, query, null);`

Comment: Tried now, but it would accidentally pick the ones from JSON as well :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use something like a regex :

for example like this one `".*\\?param1=(.*)&param2=(.*)&param3=(.*)$"` this works for your url sample that's why I added the `.*\\?` part ;)

and this will work for the first sample (`"param1=value1&param2={"url":"http://somesite.com?someparam=somevalue&someparam1=somevalue1"}&param3=value3"`
--> 
 `param1=(.*)&param2=(.*)&param3=(.*)$`

Of course if your params names aren't also something you don't know about

Comment: Ok, I tried `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\?param1=(.*)&param2=(.*)&param3=(.*)$");` then `Matcher m = p.matcher(queryString);` and then I tried to do a `find()` through matcher and it gives me no results if `m.group(1)`.

Comment: try this: ".*param1=(.*)&param2=(.*)&param3=(.*)" assuming your string does not start with a question mark